# libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop No such device E: Sub-process

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I had a problem during launching my Ubuntu this morning (but after choosing "try to repair" during booting it's finally started). Unfortunately more problems occurred during upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade [sudo] password for majkel:  Reading package
lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state
information... Done Calculating upgrade... Done The following packages
will be upgraded:   bsdutils ca-certificates compiz compiz-core
compiz-gnome   compiz-plugins-default e2fslibs e2fsprogs libblkid1
libcomerr2   libcomerr2:i386 libcompizconfig0 libdecoration0 libmount1
libsmbclient   libss2 libunity-core-6.0-9 libuuid1 libuuid1:i386
libwbclient0 mount   python-compizconfig python-samba samba-common
samba-common-bin samba-libs   smbclient sysdig ubuntu-docs unity
unity-services util-linux uuid-runtime 33 upgraded, 0 newly installed,
0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. Need to get 0 B/13,2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 951 kB of additional disk space will be used. Do
you want to continue? [Y/n]  Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ... dpkg: warning: files list file for package
'libvisual-0.4-plugins:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files
currently installed dpkg: warning: files list file for package
'libvisio-0.0-0' missing; assuming package has no files currently
installed dpkg: warning: files list file for package
'libpcrecpp0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently
installed dpkg: warning: files list file for package
'libvorbis0a:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently
installed dpkg: warning: files list file for package
'libupstart1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently
installed dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libunity-misc4'
missing; assuming package has no files currently installed dpkg:
warning: files list file for package 'libvisual-0.4-0:amd64' missing;
assuming package has no files currently installed dpkg: warning: files
list file for package 'libv4lconvert0:amd64' missing; assuming package
has no files currently installed dpkg: warning: files list file for
package 'libglib2.0-bin' missing; assuming package has no files
currently installed dpkg: warning: files list file for package
'libunity-webapps0' missing; assuming package has no files currently
installed dpkg: warning: files list file for package
'libunity-protocol-private0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no
files currently installed dpkg: warning: files list file for package
'libnss3-1d:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently
installed dpkg: warning: files list file for package
'libupower-glib1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files
currently installed dpkg: warning: files list file for package
'libvorbisenc2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently
installed dpkg: warning: files list file for package
'liburl-dispatcher1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files
currently installed dpkg: warning: files list file for package
'libuuid-perl' missing; assuming package has no files currently
installed dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libunity9:amd64'
missing; assuming package has no files currently installed dpkg:
warning: files list file for package 'liburi-perl' missing; assuming
package has no files currently installed dpkg: warning: files list
file for package 'libusb-1.0-0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no
files currently installed dpkg: warning: files list file for package
'libunity-action-qt1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files
currently installed dpkg: warning: files list file for package
'libunistring0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently
installed dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libusbmuxd2'
missing; assuming package has no files currently installed dpkg:
warning: files list file for package 'libutempter0' missing; assuming
package has no files currently installed dpkg: unrecoverable fatal
error, aborting:  unable to open files list file for package
`libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop': No such device E: Sub-process
/usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I have even tried:

```
sudo apt-get install libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop Reading package
lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state
information... Done libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop is already the
newest version. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 33 not
upgraded.
```

(unfortunately with --reinstall it doesn't work, too)
how could I properly update my Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the right solution is described at:
https://urbanjack.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/fix-unable-to-open-files-list-file-for-package-inputoutput-error/

> 1. cd /var/lib/dpkg
> 2. cp status stauts.backup
> 3. sudo nano status
> 4. ctrl + w for SEARCH enter the package name example “python2.6-minimal”
> 5. Delete the complete package block (with ctrl-k you can remove a complete line) example (removed context)
>
> Package: <*****>
>   Status: purge ok installed
>   Priority: optional
>   Section: kde
>   Installed-Size: 1234
>   Maintainer: Bla Bla 
>   Architecture: all
>   Source: oxygen-icons
>   Version: 1:2.3.5-0rasp1~berry1
>   Suggests: kdebase (>= 1:2.3.4-1)
>   Description: Bla la bla
>   Homepage: http://www.kde.org/
>   Original-Maintainer: Peter Püppel
>
> 6. Save: ctrl + o …. enter …. ctrl + x …for exit
> 7. sudo dpkg –configure -a
> 8. sudo apt-get -f install
>      and then
> 9. sudo apt-get update
> 10. sudo apt-get upgrade